# Singular solution for Lagrange differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am familiar with the following theorem:

Let $F(x,y,y')$ be defined, continuous, and with continuous first-order derivative with respect to $y$ and $y~$. Then the singular solution of the ODE $F(x,y,y')=0$ satisfies the following: $F(x,y,y')=0$ and $F'_{y'}(x,y,y')=0$.

How can I use this theorem to find the form of the singular solution for Lagrange Differential Equation $y(x)=xf(y′)+g(y′)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reference for the theorem ?

Comment: @Aryadeva Obične diferencijalne jednadžbe, prof. dr. Esmir Pilav and prof. dr. Kalabušić Senada

Comment: Thank you .....@Exzone

Comment: Mathematics is great you can read books written in languages you know nothing about and still benefit from them.